# How do I request a new tag?

Tags: support, tags

How do I request (I don't think i've the rep to create one) a new tag for this site?

I'm very surprised that there's no martial arts tag..

Edit:
Discovered I do have the rep to create one.:

How do I create a new tag?
Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...

have a maximum of 25 characters
must use the character set a-z 0-9 + # - .

Comment: You have enough rep now :)

Comment: @user00001 with great power comes great responsibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the [**privilege**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) says:

> **How do I create a new tag?**
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> have a maximum of 25 characters
>   must use the character set a-z 0-9 + # - .

The only way to make tags is to have enough rep to make a new one when asking a question or editing a question.  A regular user (as far as I can see, and I'm not entirely sure mods can either) can not make a tag outside a question.

Comment: Moderators can create a tag through the synonym interface, but that's not useful in this context.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [enough reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) (300 rep), type the new tag name when asking or editing a question. Make sure that your tag isn't a simple spelling or grammatical variant of an existing tag and that your tag fits the site's habits (have a look at the [tag list](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags) and the [tagging questions on meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags)).

If you don't have enough reputation, you cannot create a new tag. Pick one or more reasonable tags for your question, and leave a comment under your question to say what other tag(s) you had in mind. Someone will come along and add the tag (if they think it's a good idea).

Comment: And how would someone else add the tag? Would they have to use some screens only available to admins?

Comment: @AidanO No, just type the new tag in the tag box when asking the question, or to change an existing question use the `retag` button, or the `edit` button if you want to do more than change the tags. If you have enough rep, you'll be able to create a new tag.

Comment: It's 300 rep now that the site is graduated.

Answer (score -3):

There already is a [martial-arts](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martial-arts) tag

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martial-arts

Comment: There is now, there wasn't back in 2012 when this question was asked!